Класс QWidget, как использовать flags тип окна?
Читаю книгу по PyQt, не могу понять, как использовать флаг - flags.
<Объект> = QWidget([parent=<Родитель>][, flags=<Тип окна>])



QWidget::QWidget(QWidget *parent=nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f=Qt::WindowFlags())
Создает виджет, который является дочерним по отношению
к родительскому (parent),
с флагами виджета, установленными в f.
Если родительский элемент (parent) имеет значение nullptr,
новый виджет становится окном. 
Если родителем является другой виджет, этот виджет становится
дочерним окном внутри родителя. 
Новый виджет удаляется при удалении его родителя.
Аргумент флагов виджета f обычно равен 0, но его можно
установить для настройки рамки окна. 
Чтобы настроить окно, используйте значение window flags.
Если вы добавляете дочерний виджет к уже видимому виджету,
вы должны явно показать дочерний виджет, чтобы сделать его видимым.
Обратите внимание, что версия Qt для X11 может не поддерживать
все комбинации флагов стилей во всех системах.
Это связано с тем, что в X11 Qt может запрашивать только
оконный менеджер, а оконный менеджер может переопределить
настройки приложения. 
В Windows, Qt может устанавливать любые флаги, которые вы хотите.



enum Qt::WindowType \ flags Qt::WindowFlags
Этот тип перечисления используется для указания различных
свойств оконной системы виджета. 
Они довольно необычны, но необходимы в некоторых случаях.
Некоторые из этих флагов зависят от того, поддерживает ли их
основной оконный менеджер.
...


Разобрался, нужно было подключить QtCore.Qt
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget(flags=Qt.Dialog)
window.setWindowTitle("Заголовок окна")
# window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Dialog)
window.resize(300, 50)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

